# GPU Optimization: should I avoid logical OR?

Tags: optimization, shader, gpu, cg

I'm getting started writing some shader code in Cg. I've read that GPUs don't handle branching conditions very well, but I'm not sure what this means for me as a programmer. 
More precisely, I'm trying to understand which structures have performance costs.

For instance, I have some code that looks like this:

```
bool v = step( _Margin, c.y) 
         || step( _Margin, c.x) 
         || !step( 1-_Margin, c.x) 
         || !step( 1-_Margin, c.y);
```

It seems to me like the logical ORs in that statement do some conditional logic, placing a `true` value in the variable `v` **if** a certain set of conditions are met. Is this branching: is it okay, or if not, should I be going about it another way?

I don't want to step too far down the premature optimization path, but I also do want to understand what is going on here.

Comment: You're using a short-circuiting boolean or (`||`). This cannot be done without branching unless the `step` itself can be conditionally executed. Did you perhaps mean to use a bitwise or (`|`)? It will work the same for booleans, but will avoid the perhaps unnecessary overhead of short circuits.

Comment: IOW, the question you need to answer first is: Is `step` expensive enough to warrant branching around it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've done some investigation (it's necessary even if sure of the answer!)

According to Cg language specification:

> Both sides of && and || are always evaluated; there is no short-circuiting as there is in C.

And even for conditional operator (?:)

> Unlike C, side effects in the expressions in the second and third operands are always executed, regardless of the condition.

http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/Cg_language.html

It's interesting that GLSL is different here:

> And (&&) will only evaluate the right hand operand
>   if the left hand operand evaluated to true. Or ( | | ) will only evaluate the right hand operand if the left
>   hand operand evaluated to false

for conditional operator

> Only
>   one of the second and third expressions is evaluated.

https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf

Comment: Are you sure? This operator has short-circuit semantics, and should not evaluate further steps as soon as one of the partial results is non-zero.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think of short-circuiting. Will change my answer.

Comment: This is not correct. GPU languages like [tag:cg] usually differ from [tag:c]'s short-circuit semantics and evaluate all expressions even if one is found to be true. This is precisely because short-circuit semantics *would* sometimes require branching.

Comment: Ok, I've done some investigation. For cg it's correct. There is no short-circuit semantics.
For glsl 4.4 there is.